# Injecting a composite with Guice

Tags: java, guice, composite

Suppose I have an interface `Foo`.  It is implemented by concrete implementations `CompositeFoo`, `FooA`, `FooB`, and `FooC`.  Moreover, `CompositeFoo` is as follows:

```
public class CompositeFoo implements Foo {
    @Inject public CompositeFoo(List<? extends Foo> elements);
}
```

I wish to, in a Guice `PrivateModule`, bind `Foo` to a `CompositeFoo` with the list being a `FooA` followed by something that is either a `FooB` or a `FooC`.  (This must be a list, as order matters; this rules out multibindings as a solution.)

The problem is that I am seeing some circularity involved.  Suppose the provider of the `CompositeFoo` is as follows:

```
public class CompositeFooProvider implements Provider<Foo> {
    @Inject private FooA first;
    @Inject @Named("Inner") private Foo second;

    @Override public Foo get() { return new CompositeFoo(asList(first, second)); }
}
```

The module providing the second `Foo` (either `FooB` or `FooC`) is as follows:

```
public class InnerModule extends PrivateModule {
    private final Key<? super Foo> bindingKey;  // key will be exposed, bound to the Foo below

    // configure() deals with deps of FooB and FooC

    @Provides
    public Foo getInnerFoo(...) {
        // Assume that the args are such that if they are "valid", we should return a FooB, else FooC
        if (...) return new FooB(...);
        else return new FooC(...);
    }
}
```

The circularity arises when I try to construct the outer module: I need to install the `InnerModule` (passing in `Key.get(Foo.class, Names.named("Inner"))` as the binding key) in order to get the second `Foo`, but `Foo` is already bound in the outer module due to its binding to the `CompositeFooProvider`.  How do I resolve this circularity?  Will converting the `@Provides` method to its own `Provider` suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Provides Foo` method is providing a binding for `Foo` which conflicts with the `Foo` binding in the outer module.  So bind it as something else:

```
public class InnerModule extends PrivateModule {
    private final Key<Foo> bindingKey;  // key will be exposed, bound to the @Inner Foo below

    @BindingAnnotation
    @Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @interface Inner {
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(bindingKey).to(Key.get(Foo.class, Inner.class));
        expose(bindingKey);
    }

    @Provides
    @Inner Foo getInnerFoo(...) {
        // Assume that the args are such that if they are "valid", we should return a FooB, else FooC
        if (...) return new FooB(...);
        else return new FooC(...);
    }
}
```

Or perhaps you can just do

```
    @Provides
    @Exposed
    @Named("Inner") Foo getInnerFoo(...) {
        // Assume that the args are such that if they are "valid", we should return a FooB, else FooC
        if (...) return new FooB(...);
        else return new FooC(...);
    }
```

directly and not bother passing in the binding key.